# How to use Knex object in other file?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js

How do I use the knex db object inside other files?

For Example

my index.js

```
const app = require("express")();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const user = require("./routes/User");
const product = require("./routes/Product");

//-----------------
const db = require("knex")({
  client: "pg",
  connection: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "postgres",
    password: "",
    database: "Razer"
  }
});

//-----------------
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//-----------------
app.use("/user", user);
app.use("/product", product);

//-----------------
module.exports = db;

//-----------------
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("App listening on PORT 5000 ");
});
```

my User.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../index");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(db);
});

module.exports = router;
```

when am trying to use the db object inside User.js it's not working and giving me an empty object

Answer (score 0):

You are having cyclic reference between `User.js` and `index.js`. So `db` has not been created yet when you are requesting it in `User.js`.

If you really want to keep one globally declared knex instance,  you should create separate 
`db.js` file, which just creates knex and require it in both `index.js` and `User.js` files.

Answer (score 0):

**knexfile.js**

```
const path = require('path');
    
    module.exports = {
      development: {
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 3306,
          user: 'root',
          password: '',
          database: 'e_transport',
        },
        migrations: {
          directory: path.join(__dirname, './src/migrations'),
        },
        useNullAsDefault: true,
      },
    
      production: {
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 3306,
          user: 'root',
          password: '',
          database: 'e_transport',
        },
        migrations: {
          directory: path.join(__dirname, './src/migrations'),
        },
        useNullAsDefault: true,
      },
    };
```

Then crate file db.js and write the code inside file :

```
const config = require('../../knexfile')
const knex = require('knex')(config);

module.exports = knex;
```

And finally use where are you use

```
db(table).select(data).then((result) => { console.log('result', result) });
```